# restsharp First Chance Exception - Am I using it wrong?

Tags: restsharp

I am getting a first chance exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: ''' is not a supported encoding name. 
For information on defining a custom encoding, 
see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method. 
Parameter name: name'
```

using this code

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddParameter("subscription-key", API_KEY);
        request.AddParameter("api-version", 1.0);
        request.AddParameter("query", address.GetGeoCodeAddress());

        IRestResponse response = null;
        try { response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request); }
        catch (Exception ex){ }
```

Answer (score 1):

The server is probably not returning a `Content-Encoding` in the response header or the encoding specified is not supported. RestSharp currently handles this within a try-catch block resulting in the First Chance Exception. RestSharp should however default to UTF8 whenever a `Content-Encoding` is not specified.

See comments at: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/867?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container